# uart loopback code using pigpioc on buster (3B+)

Tags: serial, pigpio, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have connected pins 14 and 15; ensured that serial is enabled via raspi-config, and swapped bt to the mini UART with this line:
miniuart-bt=1
in the config file.
I then run this code:

```
int main() {
    int e;
    e = gpioInitialise();       if(e<0) err(e);
    e = gpioSetMode(14,PI_ALT0);    if(e<0) err(e);
    e = gpioSetMode(15,PI_ALT0);    if(e<0) err(e);
    printf("setup ");
    e = serOpen("/dev/serial0",9600,0); if(e<0) err(e);
    handle = e;
    printf("%d\n",handle);
    printf("send 'a'\n");
    e = serWriteByte(handle,'a');
    if(e<0) err(e);
    for(int i=0; (e = serDataAvailable(handle)) == 0 && i< 20;i++) {
        printf("."); fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
    while( serDataAvailable(handle) > 0 ) {
        printf("%c",(char)serReadByte(handle));
    }
    printf("\n");
    // and finish
    serClose(handle);
    printf("done.\n");
}
```

The handle prints as '0' and everything runs fine, but no data becomes available.
I have run out of ideas - I suspect it is something obvious but I can't see it. Any ideas?

Arrr!
Petr

Comment: "and swapped bt to the mini UART with this line: miniuart-bt=1" **WHY?** what do you think this will do? If you didn't fiddle with it it may work!

Comment: Milliways.  Can you see a solution?  I tried the "don't fiddle" approach first which did not work.  swapping which serial port is doing bluetooth so that the serial port I'm using is the more robust seems a sensible thing to try don't you think?  And how do you think it could hurt - seeing you obviously think it was stupid?

Answer (score 0):

pigpio uses the Linux serial driver to implement this function.

That means.

1. the serial link needs to be enabled at the kernel level.  The simplest way to do this is with the raspi-config utility (interfacing options).
2. There is no need to set the GPIO mode (the modes will be set by the Linux serial driver).

You have done 1 and I don't think 2 would stop it working (2 just duplicates the kernel).

Perhaps the miniuart-bt=1 is the problem.

I happen to be using a Pi3B+ at the moment with a working serial link.

The only related entry in `/boot/config.txt` is `enable_uart=1`

```
ls -l /dev/serial*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Sep 12 23:34 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Sep 12 23:34 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
```

Comment: Thanks joan, are you running buster?  I removed the GPIO mode stuff; checked the permissions & existence of the /dev/serial* and removed the  miniuart-bt statement and ensured the enable_uart was there.  Still no go.  I am beginning to think hardware but I am fairly sure it worked with my old pi4j code on the serial port under stretch.  If I can drive a LED off pin 14 and 15 then it's not hardware - is that correct do you know?

Comment: Yes, I'm using buster.  I'm using pigs. In my case the speed is 115200 so I do `pigs sero /dev/serial0 115200 0` and I'm just reading so then do `pigs serr 0 1000 -a` to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was too impatient! 20 attempts at serDataAvailable was not enough - more like 100 on a B+.

As joan said, no need to setMode for pins 14 and 15; no need to swap out the bluetooth - enable_uart=1 is all that one should find in /boot/config.txt

It seems to take about 0.8 ms for the data to come through and the final solution was to do a
usleep(100)
between calls to serDataAvailable